# Upgarde from EF 6 to EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to upgrade my project to .net Core 2.0,
I am unable to think any solution to change the below lines.

**Old Implementation:**

```
  public void ResetChangeTracking<T>(T model) where T : class, ICloneable, ICommonModel
    {
        // We might get called with a null model.  If so, just return.
        if (model == null) return;

        // Calling ObjectContext.GetObjectType helps when DynamicProxies are being used.
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx
        string key = $"{ObjectContext.GetObjectType(model.GetType())}-{model.Id}";

        if (_originalValues.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _originalValues.Remove(key);
        }
    }
```

How to make this work in .net Core 2.0?

Thanks

Comment: So you are trying to get the `Id` of an arbitrary Model from the database?

Comment: yes you are right , _originalValues stores the original model, it is a Dictionary<string, object>